# Why do I get the correct results and an error in this bash script?

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm new to bash scripting and learning "if then" statements. When I run the simple script below it executes and gives me the correct result however I still get an error. The name of the script is testscript.sh. The error is as follows: "./testscript: line 5: [csh: command not found]"

Can someone tell what this means?

```
#! /bin/bash

MY_SHELL="csh"

If ["$MY_SHELL" = "bash"
then
    echo "You seem to like the bash shell."

else

    Then "You don't seem to like the bash shell."

fi
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux. While we are happy to answer any questions regarding Unix/Linux the best method is to perform some investigation prior to asking. In the case of a new learner feel free to link to the tutorial you're following if you are using one. I googled `bash if` and the first link is a tutorial that should get you everything you need, in particular the `String comparisons` section at the end: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Answer (score 10):

Let's go through this line by line:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

MY_SHELL="csh"
```

So far, so good.

```bsh
If ["$MY_SHELL" = "bash"
```

Now this line has a number of errors:

1. `if` and not `If` - shell is case senstive so `foo` and `FOO` are different
2. There should be a space after the `[` character
3. You need a `]` at the end of the test with a preceding space.

This means the line should more like `if [ "$MY_SHELL" = "bash" ]`

```bsh
then
    echo "You seem to like the bash shell."
else
```

These are good

```bsh
    Then "You don't seem to like the bash shell."
```

You want an `echo` here.  Remember about case sensitivity.

```bsh
fi
```

The result:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

MY_SHELL="csh"

if [ "$MY_SHELL" = "bash" ]
then
    echo "You seem to like the bash shell."
else
    echo "You don't seem to like the bash shell."
fi
```

Edit: once you get more comfortable with shell scripting, https://www.shellcheck.net/ is a useful site to use to validate stuff.  The error output isn't always clear, but it's normally good for pointing out mistakes!

Comment: I doubt the code in the question even matches what the OP ran, because capital-`If` wouldn't ever try to run `[csh` as a command.  `If true;Then echo foo;fi` in an interactive shell gives `bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'`.  (Since `fi` is the first correctly-capitalized part of the whole thing, so it's actually a keyword)

Comment: thanks, not sure how the second echo command got omitted, but you answered my initial question though

Answer (score 1):

You would need a space after `[` and before `]` since brackets are actually commands!
So:

```
if [ "$shell" = "bash" ];
```

There are other errors which I didn't point out since this is the one you asked for.

Comment: I would also recommend newbies to use test command as `test "$MY_SHELL" = "bash"` to get used to thinking of it as I command. And after a while get back to brackets notation .

Comment: -1 for "other errors I didn't point out" ...